# Making nicer Android apps

Tags: android

I really don't like standard Android UIs and think that Android apps are really poor in UI compared to IOS and WP7; UIs in version >= 3.x are better, so i'm asking what can be done in making nicer apps also in versions < 3.0

Comment: Holoeverywhere lets you make most devices look like Android 4.0+ https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere

Comment: Hey!!! Not a real question, not constructive .... great StackOverflow moderators strike again. Thanks as usual....

Comment: Try re-posting in a more question oriented format such as, "Is there a way to easily create application themes on Android?" or maybe "Is there a way to easily create a styled application on Android that looks the same across all or most versions?"

Answer (score 3):

the thing to be done is have a better understanding on how to design better UI's .
this is just a poor judgement without knowledge. There are thousands of gorgeous looking apps in every API level.

read [this](http://phandroid.com/2011/05/11/10-tips-for-android-ui-design/) to get started.

Answer (score 2):

It is obvious solution: 
Use custom components. It is quite easy to make own pretty view above native one. 
The problem of native Android UI components is they could be implemented differently by different vendors. And they don't look original.

Use UI patterns (http://mobile-patterns.com/ or http://mobile-patterns.com/).